# Function to return a quoted function for a given key binding

Tags: key-bindings

I am looking for a function that returns a function (preferably quoted) for a given key binding. I know about `C-h k` (e.g. `M-x describe-key`), but I am looking for a lower-level function. (My use case is that I want to save a previous key binding before rebinding it.)

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps of interest given your question: check out `bind-key`, which is part of `use-package` (https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package). It's a nice wrapper for defining keys that let's you easily see all your personal bindings and what they've replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the aptly-named `key-binding` after reading the source code for `describe-key`:

> key-binding is a built-in function in `C source code'.
>
> (key-binding KEY &optional ACCEPT-DEFAULT NO-REMAP POSITION)
>
> Return the binding for command KEY in current keymaps.
> KEY is a string or vector, a sequence of keystrokes.
> The binding is probably a symbol with a function definition.